# Image doesn't change its source by clicking on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

Can anyone tell me why this jquery code doesn't work? In my view there is no mistake. I've compared many examples and it pretty looks the same.

```
<div id="full-view">
        <img src="" id="full-view-img" alt="#" />
    </div><!-- /#full-view -->
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("img").click(function(){

            var image = $(this).attr('id') + ".png";

            $("#full-view").fadeIn(100, function(){

                $("#full-view-img").attr('src', image);

            });

        });

        $("#full-view").click(function(){

            $("#full-view").fadeOut(100);

        });


    });
```

Thank you in anticipation!

Comment: Is your view's source just that, without `<script>` tags?

Comment: it seems like your code is just commented out html, without the script tags

Comment: Your code works if the images are in the same directory, you have script tags, and the names in the ids exist.

Comment: all is in the script-tag, i just forgot it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. JavaScript belongs in a `<script>` tag.
2. The code you provide only lists one image.  If that image is clicked, it will be hidden by the `#full-view` click handler.

If you didn't post your real code, the above issues may be just due to omissions in your post.  If that's the case, **please do the following**:

1. Edit your question to include enough correct code to fully reproduce the behavior you are seeing.
2. Post a demo at [jsfiddle.com](http://jsfiddle.com).

Regardless, this is not a great design.  The `id` attribute should not be hijacked in this way to store related data.  You can create custom attributes to do this.  I recommend using a [`data-*` attribute](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/).  This way, you can take advantage of [jQuery's `.data()` method](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

```
<img src="img_thumb.png" data-full-src="img.png" />
```

```
var image = $(this).data("fullSrc");
```

**Edit:**  Looking at [your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sHBx9/), perhaps you are simply missing a slash or two?  You have:

```
var image = "data/images" + $(this).attr('id') + ".png";
```

Is `images` the directory that contains the images? If so, you are missing the slash between the directory and the file name.  It should be:

```
var image = "data/images/" + $(this).attr('id') + ".png";
```

Or, better still, use `data-*` attributes:

```
<img src="img_thumb.png" data-full-src="img-1" />
```

And the `.data()` method:

```
var image = "data/images/" + $(this).data('fullSrc') + ".png";
```

Another thing I notice in your jsfiddle, is that one of your clickable images is a jpg, but you hard code png in your JavaScript.  If the full-sized view is always a png, that's fine.  But it would be simpler to just include the file exstension in the `data-full-src` attribute.

Comment: actually, i can't deal with your solution :/

Comment: Your jsfiddle works.  The only issue is that the images are broken because your relative urls won't work within a jsfiddle.  If I modify it to use placehold.it images, it works fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/sHBx9/1/.  If I change it further to use `data-full-src` attributes instead of `id`, it also works: http://jsfiddle.net/sHBx9/2/.

Answer (score 0):

When I run the code, the image source gets set to "full-view-img.png", but pretty much instantly fades away.

In your fadeIn function, you may need the "event.stopPropagation()" call to prevent the "fadeOut" call from happening.  Right now, when you click on the (missing) image, it just fades out since the parent div's "click" function is called.  stopPropagation will prevent the parent div function from being called.  If you want the image to fade away on the second click, you could place the $("#fullView").click statement inside the fadeIn function.

```
        $("#full-view").fadeIn(100, function(){
            event.stopPropagation();
            $("#full-view-img").attr('src', image);

        });
```

EDIT:
Also, based on the comments, make sure your javascript is inside script tags.